# Unable to locate element using cssSelector and xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I hope you can help me, I'm using selenium web driver and I want to locate a specific element in a website. I tried using cssSelector and xpath but I'm having a InvalidSelectorException and NoSuchElementException. Please see screenshot below for more details.

[image: I'm trying to locate the BACK TO HOME button]

[image: By using firebug I was able to see the underlying HTML code of the BACK TO HOME button]

I'm trying to locate the BACK TO HOME button. 
By using firebug I was able to see the underlying HTML code of the BACK TO HOME button. 
I'm not familiar on how to handle the highlighted HTML code since most of the time a link usually has a name and a cssSelector=linkText("link name") would solve the problem and a quick copy xpath command can easily locate the element. But on this scenario both cssSelector and xpath did not worked.

How do can I locate this kind of HTML code?

Comment: what CSS selector or XPATH did you use?

Comment: You can use FirePath plugin for FF to find out right XPATH for any element on the page.

Comment: @Ivan Litskevich I have already used Firepath it recognizes the xpath but when I execute it along with the java code it doesn't recognize the element

Answer (score 1):

You can try XPath as

```
//img[contains(@src,'home.gif')]
```

Since here contains method is used you can use any substring of src attribute.

Comment: I got an InvalidSelectorException. here is the code I used

`WebElement backToHome = driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\img[contains(@src, 'home.gif')]"));`
   
   `if (backToHome.isDisplayed())
   {
    backToHome.click();
   } else
   {
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home")).click();
   }`

Comment: You are using Backward Slash By.xpath("\\img[contains(@src, 'home.gif')]. Please use forward one as given in the answer.

Comment: I changed my slashes into Backward Slash, now I'm having NoSuchElementException.

Comment: Use //*/img[contains(@src,'home.gif')]. If it does not work try to check if there is any iframe in which the element is coming. If so Please set the frame using driver.switchtoframe(framename) before the method.

Answer (score 0):

I had already solved this problem. The problem was not on the xpath, it was on the code. I was trying to locate an element who is not in the page. I put my xpath code on the page where the element resides.